# How to dynamically set mixins for Reactjs Element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is there any way to add mixins programmatically for an ReactElement?
For example

```
var mymixins = {
    showLayout1(){
       return "Layout1"
    }
}
var comp = React.createClass({

   onComponentWillMount(){
       // dynamically add mixins "mymixins" to this element
       addMixins(this, mymixins);
   },
   render(){
       return this.showLayout1()
   }
});
```

The reason I'm looking for this kind of function is because Reactjs Component does not accept 2 mixins with the same method name.